# Why GA4 doesn't set timestamp that I send with event?

Tags: events, timestamp, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I'm setting server events and sending to GA4. And I need to set timestamp_micros with event. But GA4 inteface always shows me the upload date of event, not that I setted. Also I see in Bigquery export that my event has upload timestamp. I even tried to send event via [Event Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/event-builder/), but it still shows upload timestamp.
And yes, I always set timestamp within last 72 hours according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=gtag#payload_post_body)

body I send:

```
​data = {
    "user_id": "123456",
    "timestamp_micros": "1636025014649000",
    "client_id": 'TLei4bvWcgN0rPjwmbMrT2QaIDRy7It5bzc0xNJ14Ew=.1635349750',
    "non_personalized_ads": False,
    "events":[{ "name":"tutorial_begin",
        "params":{}
    }]
}
```

Does anyone know why GA4 doesn't set timestamp_micros?

Please help, it's really important.

Only the one thing that I noted that in bigquery export in column **user_propperties.value.set_timestamp_micros** in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohemw.jpg) in the rows 3 and 4 I see the exactly difference between my timestamp(setted) and ga4 timestamp(uploaded). But in column event_timestamp is uploaded timestamp. So we can say that GA4 sees my timestamp, but in the inetrface it shows uploaded timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

It works. But in my case problem was that I looked at events_intraday_* table, because in events_intraday_* table it shows only uploaded time. And in the next day when data go to the events_* table column event_timestamp will have my setted timestmap.
Also I see the right my setted timestmap in GA4 interface.

Answer (score 0):

> And yes, I always set timestamp within last 72 hours according to documentation

I was shocked that in practice if event timestamp date doesn't equal the current date (in timezone that setted in your GA4 settings) then GA4 will not catch your event.

For example, if you send event with timestamp_micros date 2023-01-23 (yesterday), but current date in timezone of your GA4 is 2023-01-24 (today) so GA4 API say 200 OK, but doesn't catch your event.

I don't know why Google do this to us :(